# Algorithm to find the sequence of bits that makes up to a given number

Tags: algorithm, c, bitwise, binary

```
int* binary (int nBits, int number)
{
    int*    bits    = calloc(abs(number)+1, sizeof(int));
    int     i       = 0;
    int     l       = nBits - 1;

    while(number > 0)
    {
        while(l >= 0)
        {
            int ln = 1 << l;

            if(ln < number)
            {
                bits[i] = ln;
                i++;
                number -= ln;
            }
            else if(ln > number)
            {
                l--;
            }
            else /* Equal */
            {
                bits[i] = ln;
                i++;
                number -= ln;
                return bits;
            }
        }
    }

    return bits;
}
```

I wrote this function in one go so it is probably quite rustic and I was curious to see what will happen if I subjected it to a review.

Provided any decimal @number and number of bits @nBits (for example 3 would mean that the function has to work with 1, 2, 4 bit representations) the function shall return the smallest sequence of bit representations (as an array of `int`s) that when added, makes up to @number
In case the number is too big, bits may repeat.

I only tested it with the numbers 0-20 for which the result is:

```
0:
1: 1
2: 2
3: 2 1
4: 4
5: 4 1
6: 4 2
7: 4 2 1
8: 4 4
9: 4 4 1
10: 4 4 2
11: 4 4 2 1
12: 4 4 4
13: 4 4 4 1
14: 4 4 4 2
15: 4 4 4 2 1
16: 4 4 4 4
17: 4 4 4 4 1
18: 4 4 4 4 2
19: 4 4 4 4 2 1
20: 4 4 4 4 4
```

I am pretty sure the code can be optimized in terms of code quality, performance and memory.
I intend to use it as an optimization for a large quantity of small entities in a game that I've been working on.

---

Example purpose:

Imagine in a game two objects *A* and *B* and we must create *N* number of entities *E* between them depending on the distance between *A* and *B*. Now to do that, *C* must be 1 pixel wide or tall (depending on the direction), which can result in a lot of C being created, which is inefficient. I figured I can draw the *C* entities with varying length (1, 2, 4, as much as I find for sufficient) and use such a function to distribute the appropriate number of them with the appropriate length. That way I will have much less entities created, but the line *C*s make across *A* and *B* will be the same.

Comment: (You haven't been that active lately.) `I was curious to see what will happen if I subjected it to a review` [CR is about insights into working code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (from one of your projects). You may be prompted to tell more about what the code is intended for (How does this `[optimise large quantities] of small entities`?), and what makes you think it works. How about `binary(30, 987654321)`?

Comment: I can agree with half of what you said, but what is the point of telling more about what the code is intended for? I don't see a reason, at all. I need it for something so specific that the chances of even everyone in the community using it for this are insignificant.
Instead, I am just sharing my code, in case someone finds it for useful. I don't require help or anything. Everyone is free to ignore it, in which case I might as well delete it. Or improve it myself.

Comment: As for the code, it definitely works. In my use case, I'd use it for much smaller numbers (say up to 1000). If a reviewer can't point out the obvious need for error-checking (such as when the allocation function fails due to an extreme allocation) or even better approach this differently so that there is no need to make such allocations or the need to use `unsigned` everywhere, then I am definitely not in the right place.

Comment: *better approach **this*** is exactly where the need for more context, for a detailed specification, for details about intended use arises. As is, all I see is code trying to give the result (in a "unary" representation) to a [change making problem with odd parameters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem).

Comment: What is a `decimal @number`, how do you pass it to `binary()`, and how would you pass a *non-decimal* one?

Comment: "_it definitely works_" - only for small values of "work".  My answer shows it has a serious bug that you didn't identify.

Comment: @TobySpeight this is essentially exacted what I stated later in the same comment. I did not change the code, because I don't want to potentially invalidate someone's answer in the process of writing it.

Comment: I possibly should have read the rest of the comment!  ;-)

Comment: Are you intentionally avoiding using bitwise operations here?  C guarantees that integer types use base 2 (aka binary), so you can do stuff like `bit = x & 1;` and `x >>= 1;` to get the next bit.  It's somewhat interesting to only use arithmetic operations that don't depend on running on a binary computer, e.g. `ln *= 2;` or `ln /= 2;` inside a loop (as a strength-reduction of the `2**n` you're doing with `1<<n`), and compares, but you are using `1<<n`.  So just wondering whether this is a missed optimization / simplification, or an intentionally arithmetic/comparison based algorithm.

Comment: Err wait a minute, you aren't serializing the number into base 2 (the sequence of bits), you're turning it into some other kind of sequence?  Like making change with a given maximum denomination?  Since `nBits` is an exponent / shift-count, this seems utterly trivial to do on the fly, and not something you'd want to actually store in an array.  e.g. `number >> nBits` of the max size, with `number & ((1<<nBits)-1)` left over for you to split up into single bits if you want

Answer (score 10):

The function has **Undefined Behaviour**.  Since `calloc()` can return a null pointer, we must not dereference `bits` (e.g. using `bits[i]`) unless we're sure it has a non-null value.

We're missing necessary includes to define `calloc` and `abs`.

We start off allowing for negative values, but then return any empty sequence (all zero).  We should either handle them fully (it's not clear from the description what the expected results should be), reject them outright (return a null pointer, perhaps?  Or change the argument to an unsigned type?), or return a minimal empty set.

The documentation needs to be a bit more specific (well, we need to have some documentation *at all*).  Notably, users need to know that the function returns memory that requires `free()` to release, and how to interpret the result array (it seems to be 0-terminated).

There's no documentation on the valid range of `nBits`, nor any checking of it.  Why do we accept negative values here?  And values larger than `CHAR_BIT * sizeof (int)` are unlikely to work how users expect right now.

The use of `l` as a variable name is a poor choice.  It's far too similar to `1` (and `I`) at a glance, which makes it hard to quickly comprehend the code.

We appear to over-allocate by a large amount.  That calculation is very pessimistic and therefore wasteful.  It shouldn't be too hard to compute the correct length to allocate.

Since we are change-making using a *complete binary sequence* of coins, the repeated subtraction is unnecessary.  For positive numbers, we can simply mask bits to obtain the count of max-value coins and the presence or absence of the smaller ones.  (E.g. the number of max-value coins is simply `number >> nBits`).

We could avoid allocating entirely, if we change our result format to return the *count* of each value returned, and require the user to provide a buffer of `nBits + 1` in length for the result.

Comment: It *DOES NOT* "have undefined behavior". The program compiles, executes and excerts undefined behavior only if `calloc fails`, which usually /but not always/ happens when large numbers are provided.

Comment: Anyway, by covering negative value cases I think you'd have pointed out the most important problems, especially when it comes to using the same function for larger values. It's probably already good to use in my game, but it is also probably needlessly obfuscated, slow and in edge cases needlessly memory hungry.

Comment: It's a semantic argument to say it has undefined behaviour only when we follow the code path where `bits` is null, given there is no way to guarantee that we never follow the other path.  In the absence of any test, that path is reachable, which is why I say it _does_ have UB.

Comment: There's probably more that could be commented on if I had a better understanding of the purpose of this code.  I spent quite a while wondering what makes it different from a change-making algorithm, but it seems that's exactly what it is, wrapped in unconventional terminology.  Am I right?

Comment: You could be very right about the unconventional terminology. I think it's a side effect from being self-taught and not a native speaker. Now, I was actually aware of the change making algorithm, but I remember it as something that does not usually use numbers which are a multitude of 2 and this algorithm rather reminded me more of how binary is interpreted. Which also reminds me of the endianness safety by the way.

Comment: If my exact use case is that important, then here it is:
Imagine in a game two objects *A* and *B* and we must create *N* number of entities *C* between them depending on the distance between *A* and *B*. Now to do that obviously *C* must be 1 pixel wide or tall (depending on the direction), which can result in a lot of *C* being created, which is inefficient. I figured I can draw *C* entities with varying length (1, 2, 4, as much as I find for sufficient) and use such a function to distribute them. That way I will have much less entities created, but the line across *A* and *B* will be same.

Comment: That's quite a useful description and would make quite an improvement to the question - I recommend you edit to include that motivating statement!

Comment: " return the count of each value returned" Did you mean return the count that the first bit repeats? Otherwise by returning the number of bits used and which are they in an array passed as an argument to the function, the user wouldn't be able to know how many times the first bit would repeat in some cases...

Comment: I wrote that in a hurry - picking 10 and 3 from your examples, you would return `{ 2, 1, 0 }`, meaning two 4s, one 2 and no 1s.  Obviously only the first value would ever be more than 1, but this might be a more useful representation.

Comment: What I did was to return the number the first bit repeats and use the array for the values. That also works.

Comment: The `number >> nBits` repeat count is so simple that this probably doesn't even need to be a separate function with an output format, just something you do as part of your drawing (?) or whatever other algorithm, with the full-size count generated in one place when you need it, and then the `number & ((1<<nBits)-1)` left-over elements done later.  If you want to break that up further, you can start with `size = 1<<(nBits-1);` and `if (size & number)` then that bit is set so do that size.  Otherwise not.  `size >>= 1;` to right-shift it.  This will iterate the low bits in `number`, @Edenia.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Toby's excellent advice, I'd like to point out that the code can be simplified without changing the algorithm.

I'll keep your variable names so that the suggested changes can be more easily compared with the original code.

First note that `l` in the inner loop can never decrease to zero. Therefore the inner loop `while(l >= 0)` is not needed at all:

```
while (number > 0) {
    int ln = 1 << l;
    
    if (ln < number) {
        bits[i] = ln;
        i++;
        number -= ln;
    } else if (ln > number) {
        l--;
    } else /* Equal */ {
        bits[i] = ln;
        i++;
        number -= ln;
        return bits;
    }
}
```

Now we see that there is no need to distinguish between the cases `ln < number` and `ln <= number`. In the latter case, `number` will become zero and the (outer) loop terminates. The early return is not needed:

```
while (number > 0) {
    int ln = 1 << l;
    
    if (ln <= number) {
        bits[i] = ln;
        i++;
        number -= ln;
    } else if (ln > number) {
        l--;
    }
}
```

Finally, instead of computing the “bit mask” `1 << l` in each iteration, we can compute it once and update it by shifting. The variable `l` is no longer needed.

```
int ln = 1 << (nBits - 1);
while (number > 0) {
    if (ln <= number) {
        bits[i] = ln;
        i++;
        number -= ln;
    } else {
        ln >>= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! That's what I expected.